# How to set trigger on 3 times Shift press in JS?

Tags: javascript

```
function Press(){
    document.querySelector("body").addEventListener("keyup", event => {
        if(event.key !== "Shift") return;
        document.getElementById("myElement").click();
        event.preventDefault();
    });
}
```

I set keyup for press Shift 1 time. How can I set it for 3 fast times? So that after Shift Shift Shift an event (document.getElementById("myElement").click()) is executed?

**UPDATE:**

this is working code made with @deceze help

```
function Press(){
    document.addEventListener("keyup", event => {
        if(event.key !== "Shift") return;
        shift_pressed = typeof shift_pressed !== 'undefined' ?  shift_pressed : 0;
        shift_pressed++;
        setTimeout(() => {
            shift_pressed= shift_pressed-1 >= 0 ? shift_pressed-1 : 0;
        }, 1000);
        if (shift_pressed===3){
            document.getElementById("myElement").click();
            shift_pressed=0;
        }
        event.preventDefault();
    });
}
```

thanks everyone for the help

Comment: Have a counter which is increases every time shift is pressed. At the same time, set a `setTimeout` which _decreases_ the counter again after some short timeout. If the counter is above 3, do your action. — Alternatively, you can store a timestamp the first time shift is pressed and again a counter, and when the counter reaches 3, check whether the timestamp is within a certain timeout range. Both methods will have slightly different behaviours, depending on how you want it to work exactly…

Comment: Consider posting an answer with working code below for the benefit of others…

Answer (score 1):

That should trigger the click on every third press of the Shift key

```
        function Press(){
            const THRESHOLD = 250;
            let counter = 0;
            let millis = Date.now();
            document.querySelector("body").addEventListener("keyup", event => {
                if(event.key !== "Shift") return;
                if(Date.now()-millis > THRESHOLD) counter = 0;
                if(++counter%3===0) { 
                 document.getElementById("myElement").click();
                 event.preventDefault();
                }
                millis = Date.now();
            });
        }
```

Comment: This doesn't account for needing to press shift thrice *within a short period of time*…

Comment: there you go, this should be good enough

Answer (score 0):

Just create `setTimeout` for clearing counter of clicking <kbd>Shift</kbd> and define `clearTimeout` clear the timeout for every single click.

```js
document.getElementById("myElement").onclick = () => {
  console.log('Hello World!');
}

let clearTime = 1000;
let counterShift = 0;
let timeout;
document.querySelector("body").addEventListener("keyup", event => {
    if(event.key !== "Shift") return;
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    counterShift++;
    console.log('number click:',counterShift);
    if(counterShift == 3) {
      document.getElementById("myElement").click();
      event.preventDefault();
      counterShift = 0;
    }
    timeout = setTimeout(()=>{
      counterShift = 0;
    }, clearTime);
});
```

```html
<button id="myElement">Test</button>
```